# Is there an easier way to combine @Transactional with logging?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying out Spring for the first time but am having a problem with @Transactional. There are certain parts of my app that I need to log exceptions in the method instead of bubbling them up to, say, `main()`. The issue though is that those methods which are labeled with @Transactional won't be rolled back if an exception occurs.

In short, this wont' work

```
@Transactional
public void doStuff() {
    try {
        //Do something that might cause an Exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception when trying to do stuff", e);
    }
}
```

Because from my understanding the transaction will never be rolled back if an exception occurs.

The only solution I could come up with:

```
public void doStuff() {
    try {
        doStuff0();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error encountered while attempting to join servers", e);
    }
}

@Transactional
protected void doStuff0() {
    //Do something that might cause an Exception
}
```

That's ugly though, uses a pattern I don't like, and is in this example almost twice as much code.

Is there another alternative to log the exception AND rollback the transaction?

Comment: Your solution by the way, does not work with JDK proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact a simple way to do what you want.  Architectural Astronaut discussions about if it's a good idea or when it' appropriate aside,  sometimes you just need it to work :) :

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

Easy as that.

Comment: OMG, this approach is recommended in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)...

Comment: recommended? : "Although very simple, this process is quite invasive, and tightly couples your code to the Spring Framework's transaction infrastructure", "You are strongly encouraged to use the declarative approach to rollback if at all possible. Programmatic rollback is available should you absolutely need it, but its usage flies in the face of achieving a clean POJO-based architecture." ..... I wouldn't call that treatment 'recommended' :)

Comment: You are right, I just spotted this piece of code in the documentation and assumed this is the way to go. I am relieved :-).

Answer (score 0):

Just rethrow the exception:

```
@Transactional
public void doStuff() {
    try {
        //Do something that might cause an Exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Exception when trying to do stuff", e);
      throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then the exception could bubble to `main()` or another method that does logging, meaning the exception gets logged twice. I'm not exactly sure what happens when an exception reaches main or the thread, but I'm pretty sure its not good

Comment: It will be caught and logged by the `@Transactional` handler (not sure at what level). If you don't want that, Affe's way is better.